# Solving for x that is in a function with sums

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So I'm dealing with an economical question.

Suppose I have $N$ items in my store and they all have a specific cost function with respect to $x$. They all have the same function (different constant terms though). Now, I want to calculate the derivative of the sum of these functions. So (correct me if I'm wrong) we know that the derivative of the sum of $N$ functions is the same as the sum of their separate derivatives (in my example these are the same).

So I have now calculated the derivative of the separate functions with respect to $x$, which is:

$$\frac{D_i}{Q_i}*S_i*(x-1)-h_i $$

And this is for every item the same, except that $D, Q, h, S$ differ per item i.
So I have as the derivative of the sum of all these separate derivatives which are the same:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{D_i}{Q_i}*S_i*(x-1)-h_i $$

Now, I want to equal this to zero and solve for $x$ ($x$ do is the same for every $i$). I've come up (and tested numerically) with:

$$x = 1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N {h_i*Q_i}}{\sum_{i=1}^N D_i*S_i} $$

My question: is this correct and can someone maybe explain this in a rigorous way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $x-1$ does not depend on index, you can simply take it out of the sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \left( \frac{D_i}{Q_i} \cdot S_i \cdot (x-1)-h_i \right)=0$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{D_i}{Q_i} \cdot S_i \cdot (x-1)=\sum_{i=1}^N h_i$$
$$x-1=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N h_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{D_i}{Q_i} \cdot S_i}$$

$$x=1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N h_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{D_i}{Q_i} \cdot S_i}=1+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^N Q_i \cdot h_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N {D_i} \cdot S_i}$$

The result is slightly different from what you came up with, check your calculations.

Comment: Indeed, I actually had $(1-x)$ and that's why. But the calculations you provided are sufficient. Thanks!

Comment: @Steven31415: glad I was able tto clarify this for you